# Is Ubuntu compatible with laptops that have touch screen features?

Tags: display, touchscreen, compatibility

Is it possible to install and run Ubuntu on a laptop with touch screen features?

Comment: In the future, I would recommend that you attempt to find answers to your question using Google. If you Google `Ubuntu touch screen`, or the title of your question, it returns information answering your question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes of course. I know some Dell and HP models that work well.

Take a look at the [Ubuntu wiki help page on touch screen devices](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen) for tips on configuration.